# SAML2AWS connecting to k8s issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, kubernetes, saml

I use saml2aws with Okta authentication to access aws from my local machine. I have added k8s cluster config as well to my machine.
While trying to connect to k8s suppose to list pods, a simple `kubectl get pods` returns an error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token' Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 255`

But if i do `saml2aws exec kubectl get pods` i am able to fetch pods.

I dont understand if the problem is with storing of credentials or where do i begin to even understand the problem.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To Integrate Saml2aws with OKTA , you need to create a profile in saml2aws first

- Configure Profile

```
saml2aws configure \
  --skip-prompt \
  --mfa Auto \
  --region <region, ex us-east-2> \
  --profile <awscli_profile> \
  --idp-account <saml2aws_profile_name>> \
  --idp-provider Okta \
  --username <your email> \
  --role arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<aws_role_initial_assume> \
  --session-duration 28800 \
  --url "https://<company>.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/......."
```

> URL, region ... can be got from OKTA integration UI.

- Login

```
samle2aws login  --idp-account <saml2aws_profile_name>
```

that should prompt you for password and MFA if exist.

- Verification

```
aws --profile=<awscli_profile> s3 ls
```

then finally , Just export AWS_PROFILE by

```
export AWS_PROFILE=<awscli_profile>
```

and use awscli directly

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: exactly, this is how I had setup and it used to work fine.

But then now I do get list of s3 instances for the profile I configured. But when i do 
```aws sts get-caller-identity``` I again get the error ```[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token'```

Comment: you can try same procedure in clean bash shell , try "env -i bash --noprofile --norc" and repeat same steps , as its common that Env variables conflict with aws/kubectl tools .